# How to configure DNS (outside Azure) and Windows VM in Azure

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, ip, windows-server-2012-r2, azure

I have just started getting to grips with moving existing websites in to Azure on a Windows Server (2012) VM.

How do I set the DNS records (managed away from Azure) to go to the site set up on that machine? Or am I approaching this all wrong, should it be set up completely differently and away from the individual server? I have also got a Public IP in Azure - but as yet I can't see how to put that to use (how would you get that to show in IIS?).

Ultimately on going to http://3.dev.[mysite].com I want this to serve a website from IIS on this VM.

**So from start to finish, this is my DNS record (again, not in Azure):**
[image: LCN DNS record showing the 4...3 ip mapped to my domain name]

**This is the VM details in Azure:**
[image: azure blade of the VM with the 4...3 ip and the 10.0.0.4 ip in details]

**This IIS on the Server where I need to set up multiple sites**
As you can see the 10.0.0.4 Address is available in the dropdown, along with a different IPv6 Address (the DNS provider doesn't yet support IPv6). I was expecting the 4...3 IP to be available there- but evidently it isn't. Do I have to map the two (so I select 10.0.0.4 but it goes to 4...3), or set the 4...3 IP to go there. Further more, or principle is this the right way of doing it? 
[image: IIS on the windows VM, showing the 10.0.0.4 ip and a IPv6 one but not 4...3]

I've looked at the following (and a lot more) so far:

- [How to Set a Static Internal Private IP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-private-ip/)
- [Step-by-Step: Assign a Public IP to a VM in Azure](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/10/28/step-by-step-assign-a-public-ip-to-a-vm-in-azure.aspx)
- - *Couple of things with this one: A) I simply can't get Powershell to recognize the commands and B) I suspect doing it like this is bad practice*

Comment: I think you're having issues because the 2nd guide refers you to the old portal and method. Resource Groups manage this slightly differently. This should set you on your way https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/ Once you have the ports allowed to the vm, you would point your dns entry at the external IP.